# Change return type from List<Func<T, bool>> to one Func<T, bool>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a function that take list of rule object and make List>
Here is my code:

```
public static List<Func<T, bool>> CompileRule<T>(List<Rule> rules)
    {
        var compiledRules = new List<Func<T, bool>>();

        // Loop through the rules and compile them against the properties of the supplied shallow object 
        rules.ForEach(rule =>
        {
            var genericType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            var key = Expression.Property(genericType, rule.ComparisonPredicate);
            var propertyType = typeof(T).GetProperty(rule.ComparisonPredicate).PropertyType;
            var value = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(rule.ComparisonValue, propertyType));
            var binaryExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(rule.ComparisonOperator, key, value);
            compiledRules.Add(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, genericType).Compile());
        });

        // Return the compiled rules to the caller
        return compiledRules;
    }
```

I want to change the function to return Func that make from compiled function and(&&) between all `Funcs` and return `Func<T, bool>`.

the rule class look like this:

```
 public class Rule
{
    ///
    /// Denotes the rules predictate (e.g. Name); comparison operator(e.g. ExpressionType.GreaterThan); value (e.g. "Cole")
    /// 
    public string ComparisonPredicate { get; set; }
    public ExpressionType ComparisonOperator { get; set; }
    public string ComparisonValue { get; set; }

    /// 
    /// The rule method that 
    /// 
    public Rule(string comparisonPredicate, ExpressionType comparisonOperator, string comparisonValue)
    {
        ComparisonPredicate = comparisonPredicate;//property name
        ComparisonOperator = comparisonOperator;//operation
        ComparisonValue = comparisonValue;//target value
    }
}
```

Comment: If you only need to put an && between them when bother? why not just return a list of expressions, and add in a foreach loop to the where clause

Comment: First off I hope you're not letting the user set this, you should be white listing your properties that you allow to filter on.  Secondly, if you're doing this dynamically, why don't you just use the Dynamic.Linq library, it will take care of building complex expressions for you.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Return a list of expressions then do foreach(var exp in expressions) { query = query.Where(exp); }. Assuming query was declared outside of loop

Comment: To bad this is closed as duplicate to some Expression based answer... you can and-combine your functions as follows: `Func<T, bool> combined = x => compiledRules.All(y => y(x));`

Comment: thanks grek40 its works perfect.

Comment: @grek40 Building and compiling a single delegate is much better than your quick and dirty solution, which involves building and compiling a lot of delegates just to introduce another delegate with inefficient LINQ call introducing closure and other garbage on each call.

Comment: @IvanStoev even though there are more efficient solutions, I see good reasons to use a self-explaining one-line of code solution (maybe renaming `x` and `y` to less generic names) as long as the code is not required to perform under heavy stress. Each line of code increases overhead when someone has to go bug-hunting, so writing 5 LOC instead of 1 should be somewhat justified.

Comment: @grek40 My point is that OP provided method can be refactored to produce the desired result with the same (or less) lines of code. There is no need of additional code used in the answer of the question marked as duplicate because in this particular case the method is not receiving external lambda expressions or delegates, but builds them from the scratch anyway. I could reopen the question, but will respect Servy's decision.

Comment: @IvanStoev if you have a solution that would be very *different and potentially better than the linked duplicates*, I don't really understand the "respect" for someones decision. You guys are granted special privileges and it really helps the community, but if you start to make a big deal of a single decision (as if it was disrespectful to reopen a duplicate under mentioned circumstances) I think that's problematic.